# Jquery mobile - page events order

Tags: jquery-mobile

What is the order of page events triggered when navigate from one page to another ?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I checked it with multi page template and found the following result:
(Navigate from A to B)

**page B**---pagebeforecreate

**page B**---pagecreate

**page B**---pageinit

**page A**---pagebeforehide

**page B**---pagebeforeshow

**page A**---pageremove

**page A**---pagehide

**page B**---pageshow

Answer (score 13):

It's actually important to note the pageload and pagebefore load events.  I had a case where I needed to clear some variables before the next page was even loaded.  So to update muhammed's list:

**page B**---pagebeforeload

**page B**---pageload

**page B**---pagebeforecreate

**page B**---pagecreate

**page B**---pageinit

**page A**---pagebeforehide

**page B**---pagebeforeshow

**page A**---pageremove

**page A**---pagehide

**page B**---pageshow

Answer (score 9):

This diagram have a better view of the process:

http://bradbroulik.blogspot.com.br/2011/12/jquery-mobile-events-diagram.html