# Jquery mobile: retrieve an element dimension on page create event

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I need to retrieve the height of .ui-navbar element.
I wrote this code:

```
var window_height = $(window).height();
$(document).on("pagecreate",function(){
    var header_height = parseInt($('.ui-navbar').height());
    console.log('header height is: ' + header_height);
    if(header_height){$('iframe#chat_ext').css({'height':window_height-header_height});}
});
```

This is my .navbar content:

```
<div data-role="navbar" class="ui-navbar" role="navigation">
        <ul id="cssmenu" class="ui-grid-c">
           <li class="ui-block-a"><a href="#home" class="ui-link ui-btn">Home</a></li>
           <li class="ui-block-b"><a href="#pool" class="ui-link ui-btn">Cerca</a></li>
           <li class="ui-block-c"><a href="#chat" class="go_to_chat ui-link ui-btn">Chat<span class="in_msg">0</span></a></li>
           <li class="ui-block-d"><a href="index.php?logout=1" data-ajax="false" class="ui-link ui-btn">Exit</a></li>
        </ul>               
</div>
```

What I get is that the log gives me "header height is: 0" when I load the page. Then if I switch some pages (usually two or three) I get the right number.
Is pagecreate an event that fires when all the elements (the one statically loaded) are in place?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576602/jquery-mobile-page-events-order) and choose appropriate event (for example, `pagebeforeshow`)

Comment: It seems there is something not working properly, I tested even with the last event firing but sometimes it gives me 0 and sometimes the right value...

Comment: If even `pageshow` doesn't show you correct value, maybe `.ui-navbar` is hide and shows up only after page loading? And are you sure that there is only one element with `ui-navbar` class?

Comment: `pageshow` (1.3) `pagecontainershow` (1.4) are the only events you can use to retrieve height, width, offset, etc.