# jQuery mobile pageload event not firing

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

```
<div id="order-preview" data-role="page">
        // header
        //ui-content
        //footer
<script>

$("#order-preview").on("pageload",function(event){
alert("aas");
});

$(document).on("pageload","#order-preview",function(event){
alert("aas");
});
</script>
</div>
```

I load this page as below

```
<a data-icon="shop" href="#order-preview">Click</a>
```

None of the two event is firing when `#order-preview` page is loaded

Comment: Have you tried using another event? Here is a nice overview about the order of the triggered events. Maybe this helps you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576602/jquery-mobile-page-events-order

Comment: $("#order-preview").on("pagebeforecreate",function(event){
alert("loaded");
});           is running twice

Comment: Yes, that's the way it's supposed to be according to the docs: https://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/ If I understand you right `pagebeforeshow` is the event you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with pageshow event, this way works for me:

```
$(document).on("pageshow","#order-preview",function(event){
      alert("aas");
});
```

I hope that this helps you!